How should brick intersect a wall with vinyl siding?
I have a 30 yo home with vinyl siding and a chimney with pipe.  I am in the process of having it replaced due to rot with stick chimney and I guess it's called brick veneer (Wood chimney box surrounded by regular brick).
The people seemingly just made the chimney wider to fit the poured slab without adjusting the siding. They mortared the brickwork to the siding. Inside, which has no brickwork yet and I can still see in the chimney area, the siding is sticking in with the vinyl F channel still attached.  I am thinking they will probably do the same thing on the roof considering the shingles - just mortar the brick to the shingles.
Right now I can put a little pressure on the siding and stick my finger into the chimney box area. How this is supposed to be done?
Inside photo above fireplace insert.

New slab

Mortared to siding


Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers.

The right way would've been to move the siding channel outside the brick face. This would've left a cleaner visual line, and it would've allowed for proper weather flashing.
I can't really tell if there's a problem here from a weatherproofing standpoint. You might do some spray testing and see where it drains. That would be my primary concern. Otherwise it's just a minor aesthetic issue.

I guess that answers my question then as to whether or not this is a proper connection (or acceptable).  I agree with you saying the channel should have been moved and said as much to them after I saw what they were doing.  I would have done it for them had I known.  But if this is how chimneys of this type are typically connected to a house, how could I complain?  I could not find any answer until now.

Masonry is typically done before siding, so no, this isn't typical. It's a shortcut approach to a retrofit of the brickwork.

And grout/mortar is the wrong material for the joint.
